# Find smallest instance satisfying certain inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities, findinstance

I need a "clean" way to find the smallest solution to some (in)equalities given by `Reduce` and containing only one variable `x`. For example, such an expression could be `1 ≤ x ≤ 2`, `x == 9` or `-1 ≤ x ≤ 4 || 7 ≤ x ≤ 11 || x == 5`. I know that `FindInstance` finds some instance, but I don't know how to restrict the search to the smallest one (it outputs `{{x -> 43/34}}`, `{{x -> 9}}` and `{{x -> 2/7}}` for the previous examples).

In principle, this could be done by using patterns to extract the endpoints of the intervals and choosing the smallest one, but I think there should be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very easily done, using `Minimize`.  Make a list of your examples

```
conditions = {1 <= x <= 2, 
  x == 9, -1 <= x <= 4 || 7 <= x <= 11 || x == 5}
(* {1 <= x <= 2, x == 9, -1 <= x <= 4 || 7 <= x <= 11 || x == 5} *)
```

and solve each of them

```
Minimize[{x, #}, x] & /@ %
(* {{1, {x -> 1}}, {9, {x -> 9}}, {-1, {x -> -1}}} *)
```